# Format for date object with am/pm

Tags: java, date, methods

I was wondering how I can just set a time such as 10:30am to a Date object from java.util.date? How would I format this? For example Date date1 = 10:30am.

Comment: There is a class called `SimpleDateFormat` that does this.

Answer (score 1):

try with the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class then output using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mma");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
System.out.println(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

can't do that.Only format to String representations.

```
SimpleDateFormat simDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
System.out.println(simDateFormate.format(new Date()));
```